# How to do a custom database setup/teardown in Spring Test Dbunit?

Tags: java, sql, spring, dbunit, spring-test

I would like to know how to create custom setups/teardown mostly to fix cyclyc refence issues where I can insert custom SQL commands with Spring Test Dbunit http://springtestdbunit.github.io/spring-test-dbunit/index.html.

Is there an annotation I can use or how can this be customized?

Comment: sorry, what is the problem you need to solve? maybe if you re-phrase it or will give an example of your problem?

Comment: Ok, let's say you have a database that has a Company and that Company has a foreign key reference to a CompanyConfig table which at the same time holds a foreign key reference to the Company id, so in order to create an entry you first have to enter a Company with a null CompanyConfig id and then after having created the company and a company config that refers to the company id foreign key you can set the Company to the CompanyConfig id you created. (I hope this makes sense) so that can be done in the @Before method but I wonder how can it be done using SpringTestDbunit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't currently an annotation that you can use but you might be able to create a subclass of `DbUnitTestExecutionListener` and add custom logic in the `beforeTestMethod`. Alternatively you might get away with creating your own `TestExecutionListener` and just ordering it before `DbUnitTestExecutionListener`.

Another, potentially better solution would be to re-design your database to remove the cycle. You could probably drop the reference from `company` to `company_config` and add a unique index to `company_id` in the `company_config` table:

`+------------+ 1   0..1 +--------------------------------+
| company    |<---------| company_config                 |
+------------+          +--------------------------------+ 
| company_id |          | config_id                      |
| ...        |          | company_id (fk, notnull, uniq) |
+------------+          +--------------------------------+`

Rather than looking at `company.config_id` to get the config you would do `select * from company_config where company_id = :id`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Phil, I will look into it, very interesting note on the design of the database too.

Answer (score 0):

Dbunit needs the insert statements (xml lines) in order, because they are performed sequentially. There is no or magic parameter or annotation so dbunit can resolve your cyclyc refences or foreign keys automatically.

The most automate way I could achieve if you your data set contain many tables with foreign keys:

1. Populate your database with few records. In your example: Company, CompanyConfig and make it sure that the foreign keys are met.
2. Extract a sample of your database using dbunit Export tool.

This is an snippets you could use:

```
IDatabaseConnection connection = new DatabaseConnection(conn, schema);
configConnection((DatabaseConnection) connection);
// dependent tables database export: export table X and all tables that have a // PK which is a FK on X, in the right order for insertion
String[] depTableNames = TablesDependencyHelper.getAllDependentTables(connection, "company");
IDataSet depDataset = connection.createDataSet(depTableNames);

FlatXmlWriter datasetWriter = new FlatXmlWriter(new FileOutputStream("target/dependents.xml"));
datasetWriter.write(depDataset);
```

After running this code, you will have your dbunit data set in "dependents.xml", with all your cycle references fixed.

Here I pasted you the [full code](https://github.com/antoniomaria/gazpachoquest/blob/master/tools/dbextractor/src/main/java/net/sf/gazpachoquest/extractor/dbunit/DBUnitDataExtractor.java): also have a look on [dbunit doc about how to export data](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#streaming).

Comment: Yes I know I have to use data sets, my question is how to solve the cyclic reference insertion and teardown gracefully possibly using annotations (by manually setting the Company config id to null in both operations) using Spring Test DbUnit annotations instead of a manual solution, in other words, how can I do a custom setup and teardown of the database that in our project we do by extending Db unit's DBTestCase and overriding @Before and After and at the same time use the spring test dbunit framework?